# Can I use component in ItemSeparatorComponent in flat list?

Tags: react-native, separator, react-native-flatlist

I was thinking about how to use  [ItemSeparatorComponent](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#itemseparatorcomponent) in Flat list

It works if I use :

```
import Seperator from '../Seperator';

        <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <Seperator />}
          data={this.props.x}
          renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderX(item)}
        />
```

Can I just use `<Seperator />` like the following?

```
import Seperator from '../Seperator';

           <FlatList
              ItemSeparatorComponent={ <Seperator />}
              data={this.props.x}
              renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderX(item)}
            />
```

It doesn't work! Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `<Separator/>` is a stateless component without lifecycle methods, you could change them to functional components like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {View} from 'react-native'

const Separator= (props) =>
  <Text>{...}</Text>

export default Separator
```

In doing so, you don't need an explicit return. If you stick with class components (with state, lifecycle-methods or render...), you need to use arrow functions (implicit return).

Answer (score 3):

The reason `() => <Separator />` works and `<Separator />` does not is because `ItemSeparatorComponent` expects a *function* that renders an element, not the element itself.

This is because the component you specify as a separator is being dynamically rendered as the list is being populated, instead of it being rendered in place (which is what the `<Component />` syntax does).

In your working example, you are using `() => <Separator />`. Unless you are using class components, this is redundant, as all that your code does in that case is create an anonymous function that then renders your component.
Provided that you are using a stateless function component (which one would expect a mere separator to be), you could just write it as `ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}`